# Rails 3 console sandbox refresh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a ruby-newbie following along with the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. In chapter 6 we are creating validation rules for our User model and manual testing in the console sandbox. When I change a rule in my model, it is not reflected in the console tests. i.e. saving a new user with no name is allowed even though I just created that validation in my model.

```
validates :name, presence:true
```

If I exit the console and then restart the console, everything works as expected. Is there another way to refresh or am I doing something wrong altogether?

Answer (score 2):

type this into console:

```
reload!
```

Comment: that took me out of sandbox and committed the transaction. So exiting the console later would not allow rollback. Is there a similar method to reload! that will keep me in the sandbox and not commit the transaction?

Comment: "run the console in a sandbox—meaning that all your database changes are completely reverted when you exit the console."

Comment: @14113 the problem is that `reload!` exits the sandbox